# É possivel retornar um Observable<boolean> da requisição get

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso verificar se a api está ativa. Basicamente estou tentando verificar se o status da requisição é igual a 0; se for, sei que a api está fora do ar.

Mas eu queria colocar esse método na minha classe service e só retornar true ou false pra quem for usar ele, sem precisar chamar um subscrible e fazer as verificações.

```
verificarServer(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.http.get('http://' + this.HOST + ':' + this.PORT + '/' + this.API).subscribe(
      s => {  },
      e => {
        if(e.status == 0){

        }else{

        }
      }
    );

  }
```

Esse é um código que estou tentanto, seria algo mais o menos asssim que eu precisaria.
Algo que me retorna true ou false em um observable.

Como eu poderia resolver isso ?

**Edit1**

O código usando o map não funciona (exemplo dessa [resposta](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/43683143/7857065))
Estou usando o http de `HttpClient`

```
 this.http.get('http://' + this.HOST + ':' + this.PORT + '/' + this.API).map((response:Response)=>{
      console.log("imprime alguma coisa aqui Cara#$*&¨#*");
      console.log(response.status);
    });
```

não cai dentro da funcão `map`

Comment: Acho que talvez essa resolução te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683143/7857065

Comment: valeu, mas não deu certo não, eu estou usando HttpClient, acho que o que está nessa resposta é o Http. Alguns métodos que está na resposta nem existem para o HttpClient. Eu coloquei o map na requisição get pra testar, aparentemente, nem cai na dentro do map.

Comment: Você pode retornar usando `get<boolean>(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após efetuar a requisição através do método `get`, utilize dentro do `pipe` um `map` para verificar se o status retornado é zero projetando um valor booleano. Na sequência utilize um `catchError` retornando `of(false)` para tratarmos os possíveis erros. Neste formato seu método sempre irá retornar um `boolean`. Utilize o exemplo abaixo para adaptar o método da sua service:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed', { observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(
            map(a => {
                console.log('status', a.status);
                return a.status === 200;
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('Erro na requisição', err);
                return of(false);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            (a: boolean) => console.log('Resultado', a)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que se está a passar aqui é que estás a tentar retirar um valor de um ["cold Observable"](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html) isto acontece quando tu não te subscreves a um evento (neste caso, ao evento que é retornado do `http.get()`.

Isto pode ser resolvido de três maneiras:
1) no teu componente, fazes o `.subscribe()` depois de chamares esta função
2) no teu service, fazes um .subscribe() nessa função e envias o valor  *por outro* observable que seja disponibilizado pelo serviço
3) passar esse cold observable para uma Promisse e resolver essa promessa no lado do componente